# cscart display products (products in selected category) in cs-cart content page

Tags: cs-cart

Is it possible to add selected products/categories in cs-cart page (created using websites -> content -> add page) in cs-cart3?

I have created the page using websites -> content -> add page. Try to edit page and clicked on block tab, but some how it is not allowing me to add block/filterblock it.

If you see attached screenshot, there is no add block option available?

Any idea?[image]

Answer (score 0):

In administrator Area click on

```
Design -> Blocks -> Pages (tab)
```

In Blocks, under "Main Content" click on Plus Icon

```
Add Grid or BLock -> Add Block -> click on "create new Block" (tab) and select products or categories, finally give this block name and select type "Manually"
```

New Block will be added under "Main Content" (you can also disable this newly created block for specified pages(which you select)

Now to add products or categories Manually go to

```
admin area -> website -> contents -> click on edit page (for page you wish to edit)

click on Block tab -> finally click on Cog of newly created block to add/select product for that specific page.
```

Note above instruction are for CS-Cart 3, I hope it might be same for cs-cart 4 as well